# MVVM Pattern Listview

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I am new to WPF and saw few good videos about MVVM and WPF, however I get confused when I try to show a list of data. For some reason I get no data, in my listview. Here is my class

Model/Person.cs

```
class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        // 1. Fields, Constants
        private int ID;
        private string FirstName;
        private string MiddleName;
        private string LastName;
        private DateTime Birthday;
        private string Prefix;
        private string Email;

        public Person(int ID, string FirstName, string MiddleName, string LastName)
        {
            this.ID= ID;
            this.FirstName = FirstName;
            this.MiddleName = MiddleName;
            this.LastName = LastName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the person first name
        /// </summary>
        public string firstName
        {
            get { return FirstName; }
            set { 
            FirstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the person middle name
        /// </summary>
        public string middleName
        {
            get { return MiddleName; }
            set { 
                MiddleName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MiddleName");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the person last name
        /// </summary>
        public string lastName
        {
            get { return LastName; }
            set { 
            LastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get or Sets the person birthday
       /// </summary>
       public DateTime birthday
       {
            get { return Birthday; }
            set { 
                Birthday = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Birthday");
            }
        }


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

Then I have my View/Person.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Person : Window
    {
        public Person()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvDataBinding.DataContext = new PersonViewModel();

        }
    }
```

The xaml is as follow:

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding Person}" Grid.Column="1" Width="auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding firstName}" Header="First Name" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastName}" Header="Last Name" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding middleName}" Header="Middle Name" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Birthday}" Header="Birthday" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

Last pieces but important here is my ViewModel/PersonViewModel.cs

```
internal class PersonViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> myData { get; set; }

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        List<Person> myData = new List<Person>();

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> getData()
    {
        myData.Add(new Person(12456, "John", "Francis", "Dufour"));
        myData.Add(new Person(12456, "Heather", "Meagan", "Cornthwaite"));
        if (myData.Count > 0)
        {
            return myData;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

I am totally of the chart or is something very small that needs to be fix? Also does it actually follow the MVVM pattern, and in the future I plan to have access to a database, does this pattern work well for me in the future for this.

Comment: Instead of updating original question, always add the edit at last. Otherwise, posted answers related to your original question will lost its value. You completely edit the code which it was earlier when you posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***First*** of all collection name is **`myData`** and not **`Person`**. So, change ItemsSource to bind to myData property:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myData}">
```

Also, I would suggest to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` in case you want your UI to update on add/remove of item in collection because ObservableCollection implement **`INotifyCollectionChanged`** which is responsible for notifying UI on any change in collection.

Replace

```
public List<Person> myData {get; set;}
```

with

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> myData {get; set;}
```

---

***Second***, you can only bind with properties and not fields. So change all fields in Person class to properties and make them public.

```
public int ID {get; set;} // Same for other properties.
```

Since you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, make sure you raise the event properly from all property setters. So, ideal property should look like:

```
private int id;
public int ID
{
   get
   {
      return id;
   }
   set
   {
      if(id != value)
      {
         id = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ID");
      }
   }
}
```

---

***Third***, binding path property is case sensitive. Make sure you spell the binding correctly:

It should be FirstName instead of firstName.

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"
                Header="First Name" Width="100"/> // Same for other columns.
```

---

***Fourth***, you never filled the objects in the collection. Method **`getData()`** is never called. Fill the collection in constructor itself.

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> myData {get; set;}

public PersonViewModel()
{
   myData = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
   myData.Add(new Person(12456, "John", "Francis", "Dufour"));
   myData.Add(new Person(12456, "Heather", "Meagan", "Cornthwaite"));
}
```

Comment: I have apply your change and it still is not working, I will update the post to include your change and maybe i am missing something

Comment: Thank you, very much, I think the myData myData wasthe main issue, thank this make more sense.