# Binding ListView using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to bind ListView control with List in viewmodel. It doesn't work, I found that thread in stackoverflow:
[MVVM Pattern Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714844/mvvm-pattern-listview)
and following an answer I changed List on ObservableCollection.
After compilation I can add new object to the listview, but they are empty, though I set them default value in the command.
What did I wrong? How can I bind my collection correctly?

XAML code:

```
        <ListView Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="4" x:Name="ProductListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Products" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

<Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddProduct}" />
```

ViewModel code:

```
        public MainViewModel(MainWindow view)
        {
            model = new MainModel();
            this.view = view;

            Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            Products.Add(new Product() { Name="Example"});
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
        {
            get => model.Products;

            set
            {
                model.Products = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Products));
            }
        }


        public ICommand AddProduct
        {
            get
            {
                addProduct = new RelayCommand((object o) => {

                    Products.Add(new Product() { Name="New product"} );

                }, null);

                return addProduct;
            }
        }
```

Model code:

```
internal ObservableCollection<Product> Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
```

Comment: Where and how do you set the `DataContext` of the view?

Comment: public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(this);
        }

Comment: Why are you injecting a view model with a view? This breaks the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I write about that below. It was only for tests.

Comment: Do you see the `ListView` at all?

Comment: From VM? Yes, I do, also ListView.ItemsSource see properties from a viewmodel.

Comment: On the screen...

Answer (score -1):

I advise you to remove the setter of the Products property: `public ObservableCollection<Product> Products`. The problem is when you assign it after the binding was done, you'll adding items to a different collection.

Use this instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; } = 
    new ObservableCollection<Product>();
```

---

This `this.view = view;` is unknown to me. Should it be `this.DataContext = view;`?

---

With my *(intermediate)* knowledge of MVVM:

- View Binds to the data of the ViewModel
- ViewModel holds the datastructure (also owner of creating ObservableCollections)
- Model uses the data in the ViewModel to manipulate the data. (so indirectly the View)

So put the `public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();` in the ModelView instead of the Model.

Comment: I changed internal on public in model, nothing changed. I binded DataContext with viewmodel in a view's constructor, but it is for tests, I'm trying everything, also binding and operations on listview in a viewmodel's command.